# Am I doing this knockout binding incorrectly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0

The **view** code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: BackColorOptions">
    <li data-bind="css: { selected: Selected }">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="BackColorOption" 
                data-bind="value: Color, checked: $root.BackColor" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
@{
    var jsonModel = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.
        JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}
<input type="hidden" id="JsonModel" value='@jsonModel' />
```

The **viewmodel** code:

```
var initialData = $.parseJSON($('#JsonModel').val());

function BackColorOption(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.parent = parent;
    self.Text = ko.observable(data.Text);
    self.Color = ko.computed(function () {
        return '#' + self.Text().toLowerCase();
    });
    self.Selected = ko.computed(function () {
        var backColor = self.parent.BackColor();
        if (backColor) {
            return backColor.toLowerCase() == self.Color;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.BackColor = ko.observable(initialData.BackColor);

    var mappedBackColorOptions = $.map(initialData.BackColorOptions, 
        function (item) {
            return new BackColorOption(item, self);
        }
    );
    self.BackColorOptions = ko.observableArray(mappedBackColorOptions);

}

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
```

The **model** code:

```
string BackColor { get; set; }
SelectListItem[] BackColorOptions
{
    get
    {
        return new[] 
        { 
            new SelectListItem{Text = "cc0000"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "ff9900"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "dddd33"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "009900"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "00cccc"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "0066ff"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "9900ff"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "ff00ff"},
        };
    }
}
```

The code above works as expected in IE (8) and Chrome (17), but not FF (10.0.2). I'm basically trying to do a color selector similar to GitHub's issue labels. The view renders a set of radio buttons you can click on to choose a color. When a radio is checked, I add a `selected` css `class` to the parent `<li>`. The css class causes a checkmark icon to appear over the `<li>`.

In Firefox, the selected css class is only applied after a user has gone through and checked each radio button at least once. I debugged and found that this is because of the way the `self.Color` computed observable is evaluated in the `BackColorOption` closure. Before the first time a radio is checked, `typeof(self.Color) == 'function'` evaluates to true. However after it is checked, `typeof(self.Color) == 'string'` evaluates to true.

This `typeof(self.Color)` behavior is the same according to both Firebug and Chrome's js debugger. However the issue in FF is because of this line in the `self.Selected` computed observable in the `BackColorOption` closure:

```
return backColor.toLowerCase() == self.Color;
```

Chrome & IE still return true even when `self.Color` is a function instead of a string. However Firefox does not. When `self.Color` is a function, it returns false. This is why you have to check each radio at least once before the css class is added to the `<li>` and the icon appears.

I'm still a bit new to knockout, and may not be appropriately calling a viewmodel property as a function when supposed to. I'm still a little unclear when to use the `()` parenthesis and when to omit them. Is there another way I should write the `self.Selected` computed observable, which depends on the `self.Color` computed observable (in the `BackColorOption` closure)?

**Update 1**

I was able to get this to work in FF 10.0.2 with the following:

```
self.Selected = ko.computed(function () {
    var backColor = self.parent.BackColor();
    var selfColor = self.Color;
    if (typeof (selfColor) === 'function')
        selfColor = self.Color();
    if (backColor) {
        return backColor.toLowerCase() === selfColor;
    }
    return false;
});
```

However, this feels like I'm fighting knockout. Isn't it supposed to "just work"?

Comment: Could you knock up a jsfiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUKGh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` binding in KO is not really ideal for radio buttons and checkboxes. In your situation you need your radio buttons to have a `value` attribute so that when you click them, that value can be used to update your `TestViewModel.BackColor` observable.

Normally with radio buttons, you don't want the `value` attribute to change (if ever) once the html is rendered.

So, I've changed your html template from using a `value` binding to instead using an `attr` binding (html attribute). This is now just setting the `value` html attribute of your radio buttons. The `checked` binding then keeps your `TestViewModel.BackColor` observable synced with whatever the `value` is of the radio button that is checked.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m2KQ2/

Also, the line in your `BackColorOption` function has a typo:

```
self.Selected = ko.computed(function () {
    var backColor = self.parent.BackColor();
    if (backColor) {
        return backColor.toLowerCase() == self.Color; //<-- should be Color();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, yes, that works. It didn't occur to me to bind the value using the attr binding rather than the value binding. You are exactly right, I don't want the radio button value to change. I did notice your fiddle was invoking self.Color() as a function, and updated my code accordingly.